# is it possible to dispatch function when react component is unmount ? (React functional componet)

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm making some function which call api and save that value in the state, and then it should dispatch when user leave the component. so I tried to use react useEffect hooks as componentWillUnmount and dispatch some action with argument as state value.
but the problem is  dispatch action is work but with empty string.. I think somehow state value is deleted and then dispatch function is executed.So is there's any way that I call function with state value, when user leave the component?

```
const [userCheck,setUserCheck]=React.useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  
  const fetChItem='this is the function which calling api '
    setUserCheck(fetChItem);

}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    dispatch(saveFetchValue(userCheck));
    
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Issue

This won't work because of how enclosures work with the `useEffect` callback. With the following

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    dispatch(saveFetchValue(userCheck));
  };
}, []);
```

You have enclosed the initial `userCheck` state value (`""`) in the returned cleanup function.

## Solution

Use a react ref and a second `useEffect` hook to "cache" the latest state.

```
const [userCheck, setUserCheck] = React.useState('');

const userCheckRef = React.useRef(userCheck); // ref to store state value

React.useEffect(() => {
  userCheckRef.current = userCheck; // save userCheck state value to ref
}, [userCheck]);

...

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    dispatch(saveFetchValue(userCheckRef.current)); // pass current ref value
  };
}, []);
```

Demo

[image: Edit is-it-possible-to-dispatch-function-when-react-component-is-unmount-react-fun]

Comment: FYI the order of the useEffect blocks actually matters

Comment: @HyperActive Yes. Are you referring to the `useEffect` that is setting the ref value so it's available in the second `useEffect` hook with cleanup function?

Comment: ya, just a note to anyone that stumbles here.  I didn't realize at first but the order of those`useEffect`'s matter

Comment: @HyperActive and others, affirmative, React hooks are called in the same order they are defined each render cycle. In the case of refs that can be set/updated at any time during the render cycle, if one hook depends on any updated ref values then the order between the hooks setting the ref value matters.